# Trove4j library cannot be resolved

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile my app:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':myProject'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':myProject:classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
         https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
         https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
     Required by:
         project :metam > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0-beta2 > 
com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.0-beta2 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.0-beta2 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-
api:26.0.0-beta2 > com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.0-beta2
```

It appears a library the IDE needs is missing?

Comment: Do you have proxy on your environment? this needs to be configured on the IDE to download gradle packages.

Comment: Unsure. How would I check?

Comment: First, check your network settings on PC if it has proxy

Comment: Thanks, no proxy before and none now.

Answer (score 124):

this issue can be resolved by adding jcenter() as a repository in the buildscript section.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
     jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
  }
}
```

Comment: Specifically, replace `mavenCentral()` with `jcenter()`

Comment: This must be added in your modul'e's gradle, not the projetc's one.

Comment: Add jcenter to all repositories declared in the gradle file

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am not sure why I should replace `mavenCentral()` which `jcenter()`, when I could simply append `jcenter()` to the list of repositories. Care to elaborate why you suggest that?

Comment: @Flow `jcenter()` overlaps with Maven Central. You would only add both if you cannot reach JCenter for some reason

Comment: Ok, so it overlaps with Maven Central, some artifacts can be found in both. But I don't see how this is an argument to replace the one with the other. If anything, adding both would increase the reliability of the build.

Comment: jcenter is going to be sunset on May 1, 2021. This solution might work only until then. 

Specifically, DONOT replace `mavenCentral()` with `jcenter()`.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix this without adding `jcenter()`?

Comment: @AlejandroH.Cruz, yes, see answers below.

Comment: For me today, this didn't resolve anything and just told me "JCenter is at end of life"

Comment: Finally, `jcenter()` is about to shutdown, so this and similar answers won't stay correct, anymore.

Answer (score 70):

Additional to [Snicolas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45874378/809944):

If you have something like:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter() //also add it here!!!
    }
}
```

In your `build.gradle` file; also add it there.

Comment: replace mavenCentral() with jcenter(). it will work

Comment: Thanks. I mistakenly added jcenter() into "buildscript" section instead of "allprojects".

Comment: Any suggestion on what to do now that jcenter is being shut down in May?

Comment: Finally, jcenter() is about to shutdown, so this and similar answers won't stay correct, anymore.

Answer (score 15):

**Since jCenter will close** [in May](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/), you should change `root/build.gradle` so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66168563/2914140 to add libraries not included in Maven.

Now we can build apk without errors.

Comment: This is the currently most correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you're seeing this error after May 1st 2021, it's probably because [jcenter is shut down](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/). It's needed by the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP). Google devs have said they're using a newer version of the library that can be got from `mavenCentral()` as of AGP 7 and hoping to backport that into AGP 4.2 and 4.1. So first of all, try and upgrade to AGP 7. And if I haven't edited this post with updates, check to see is it in any lower AGP versions.

But if you can't upgrade AGP, as of initial time of posting (February 2021), the only repo I could find with the trove package is on pentaho, which seems to be owned by Hitachi so I presume it's safe.

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
         maven { url "https://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni" }
   }

   dependencies {
         classpath 'org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824'
   }
}
```

This is NOT an ideal solution. This repo could be intended to be private for all I know. Look for a better answer that might be posted after me.

Comment: Do you have a link to where the Google dev's discussed Trove4j and AGP backporting?

Comment: @ScottMarkwell https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/lbssfn/now_that_bintray_and_jcenter_are_shutting_down/glwj7ms/?context=3

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem 
deleting in build.gradlew

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

And change the mavenCentral() to jcenter() and deleting google()

Answer (score 6):

**Migrating away from jcenter?**  *jcenter will sunset on the **1st of May***

You may face this issue if you are migrating away from jcenter. The issue happens because Trove4j library was being fetched from jcenter and you removed jcenter repository while migrating away from jcenter.

**Solution:**

Add the following to the project build.gradle:

```
maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
```

It should be added to:

1. build.gradle(peoject) -> buildscript -> repositories
2. build.gradle(peoject) -> allprojects -> repositories

   ```
   buildscript {

       repositories {
           google()
           mavenCentral()
           // ** Add this line **
           maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           mavenCentral()
           // ** Add this line **
           maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
       }
   }
   ```

Since jcenter will sunset on 1st of May, 2021. jcenter repository should be removed from the project. This means that all occurrences to "jcenter()" should be removed. This can lead to an issues with the libraries hosted by jcenter. You should provide another repository that host the library such as maven. Some unmaintained libraries maybe are not moved to any other repository. In this case, you might need to consider opening an issue for the library or not using it. You will face all these issues on the 1st of May and **you may be unable to build your app** if you are not doing the migration now.

Answer (score 4):

Just delete .idea,.gradle and gradle folder and restart your application.

Comment: it worked for me after I though I have every library version clash resolved, and updated also build tools, target API, etc... and I was getting all kind of weird errors (both like this Trove4j or on subsequent builds with support libraries versions), unable to even search where those old versions pop out from...  (nope, actually it's back, so it didn't help ... :/ )

Comment: In the end I had to replace maveCentral() repository with jcenter() for both builtscript and app, which resolved the Trove4j issue, but this deletion of old cached files and reimporting of project at least seemed to stabilized output of build process

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace `mavenCentral()` with `jcenter()` in your `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

        jcenter() 
      //.......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to Help->About in Android Studio and check your version. Enter that vesion in build.gradle App Mudule & same for project build.gradle as done in the 
`classpath` line here:

```
buildscript {
     ...
    repositories {
     ...
    }
    dependencies {
     ...
     classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:{THREE.DIGIT.VERSION}"
    }
}
```

[image: Like in image]

Answer (score 1):

**This was happening to me every time I upgraded the Gradle Plugin, so what I did and worked:**

1. Delete your package-lock.json or yarn.lock
2. Run `npm i` or yarn to update all node modules in your project
3. Rename your ios project to ios_ for example
4. Run `react-native link` to link all dependencies again to your android project
5. Rename back ios_ to ios
6. Check the file (project/build.gradle) what Gradle Plugin version you're using. The version 3.4.1 worked for me.
7. Check your Gradle version (gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties), the version 5.4.1 worked here.
8. Open your Android project using Android Studio, navigate to Build > "Rebuild project"
9. And finally, try sync/build again.

Hope it can help someone.