# Gradle Dependencies issue: Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to list my project's dependency tree. So I ran `gradle dependencies`
 and got the following:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'Android'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            http://maven.fabric.io/public/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
>            http://maven.fabric.io/public/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
>        Required by:
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-c
>   hecks:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1

I can't find any help on internet. But I'm still on the tracking.

Any help would be welcome ;]

Comment: this may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818613/trove4j-library-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 12):

This happens to me when I open a very old project in gradle 3.1
to solve it I added:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
```

To both gradles files (app gradle file and project gradle file)

Answer (score 5):

You must replace `mavenCentral()` with `jcenter()`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this problem by changing the order of repositories

from this:

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
```

to this:

```
repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
```